# C++ applying "typing" on an array of elements

Tags: c++, polymorphism

**EDIT:** This is a school assignment, I didn't decide on this design so please don't suggest to change it.

Consider the following hierarchy :

```
        A
       / \
     B     E
    /\ 
   C  D
```

I have an array of pointers to A (A**) , and I need to create two methods :

- First one counts every object of type B and its relatives.
- Second one counts only the object of exactly B type.

For the first one I'm using this code:

```
int countTypeOfBs(A** arr, int size){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (dynamic_cast<B *>(arr[i]))
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

And I'm stuck with the second one, I've tried this :

```
int countBs(A** arr, int size){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (!strcmp(typeid((*A[i])).name(), "B"))
                count++;
    return count;
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying expression must have a constant value ..

How can I solve this ?

*EDIT:* It was a typo, I accidently used `A[i]` instead of `arr[i]` . It fixed the problem .

Comment: `A**` is not an array (of anything). It's a raw pointer. Arrays of pointers to A are spelled in C++ this way: `std::vector<shared_ptr<A>>` (or `unique_ptr`). But that's beside the point. It looks like you have a design issue. There should be no valid use case for knowing the most derived type of an object. If you think you have one, you are probably doing something wrong. If you are doing a dynamic cast, you are most likely doing something wrong too.

Comment: @n.m. This is a school assignment, I didn't decide on this design .

Comment: The design is, to put it mildly, questionable and it doesn't buy your school any points. Anyway, you need to compare typeids, not their names. Names are not guaranteed to be unique, nor they are guaranteed to resemble C++ identifiers they come from. Last but not least, you wrote `A[i]` where you meant to write `arr[i]`.

Comment: @n.m. Yup, that was the problem , just noticed it . everything worked beside it .

Comment: Working is an [illusion](https://ideone.com/feezUQ).

Comment: @n.m. depends on the task .

Comment: @JesperJuhl Like it.  Just so you all know that I'm a geek too: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/6344-time-is-an-illusion-lunchtime-doubly-so

Comment: @JesperJuhl Oh, you deleted your comment.  Shame, it was funny.  Too many stuffed shirts on here.

Answer (score 4):

The [`typeid`-operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) can be applied to a type, or an expression, and returns a reference to the appropriate [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) object. And those can simply be compared with [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) for equality.
The implementation will know whether reference-equality is enough, or it needs a string-comparison, don't try to second-guess it.

Comment: I was under the same impression but this test is showing me otherwise. Why is the result false? https://onlinegdb.com/SkJdWiyX7

Comment: @Rotem there's a typo you want to fix before trying the test.

Comment: Well, haha , I found my problem.. I accidently used `A[i]` instead of `arr[i]` . Everything works now .

Comment: @n.m. If there is I don't see it. Care to explain?

Comment: @Rotem Look at your pointers types. And remember your classes are not polymorphic.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, the pointer types were not an accident, I just forgot to add a virtual function.